# Vue.js testing with jest, class-binding failure

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, frontend, vue-component

I'm trying to test a component, which should be hidden on users click. Functionality works in the browser, but the tests are failed during automated testing with Jest.

Here is the test:

```js
 it(`If the local variable is set to be clicked, 
     then the tip is hidden`, () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component, { props });
    wrapper.setData({ was_clicked: true });
    wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
    expect(wrapper.classes()).toContain("hide"); // fails here
    expect(wrapper.find(".toast").isVisible()).toBe(false);
});
```

Here is the component:

```js
<template>
    <div @click="hide" class="toast" :class="{ hide: was_clicked }">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: ...,
    data() {
        return {
            was_clicked: false,
        };
    },
    props: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        hide(event) {
            this.was_clicked = true;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I was trying to add and remove `wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();` from the test, also, I tested the `nextTick` of `wrapper.vm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();` returns a promise. You should either `await` that promise (and mark the function as `async`), or move the `expect()`s after it to a `.then`. The same thing applies for `vm.$nextTick();`. Here is the code that worked with me:

```js
it(`If the local variable is set to be clicked, then the tip is hidden`, async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Tip, { props });
    wrapper.setData({ was_clicked: true });
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.classes()).toContain("hide");
    expect(wrapper.isVisible()).toBe(false);
});
```